# I want to select a date in access

Tags: c#-4.0

select date from table1 where date <=(select Format(date,'mm/##/yyyy') as dates from table 2).
This query returns "02/##/2011".
I want to make a list like "02/02/2011","02/03/2011" etc.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with your query, if its a query. change your query by putt star (*) instead of hash(#).